# Formatting decimal to string of length 9, 2 digits (0 padded) before '.' and 6 after it

Tags: c#, biztalk

I am a newbie in Biztalk and C#, I am trying to format the number in such a way that below requirement can be fulfilled

```
33.00 -> 33.000000
0.00 -> 00.000000
65.7777777 (random example that results in rounding) -> 65.7777777
```

So far I am successful with right padding. Below is the code

```
Param1 = "2.00"
    if (param1.Contains(".")) 
     {
      Decimal convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(param1);
      String temp=convertDecimal.ToString("F6", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
      Console.WriteLine(temp); 
    }
```

Output : 2.000000
Expected Output : 02.000000

Any idea how can the leading zeros be included?

Comment: What is wrong with you code since it is working?

Comment: Try `convertDecimal.ToString("00.000000", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: Can you possibly get a value of 100 or higher, as that clashes with the "2 digits before decimal" requirement?

Comment: @SomeBody - that would round though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a leading `'0'` you can use padding or fix your format string to include a leading 0.

As for omitting rounding of `67.77777777777` to `67.7777778` you can format it to one digit more and use [string slicing](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemrange) to remove the rounded digit:

```
using System;

var precision = 7;

// add a leading 0 and add precision + 1 digits after 0
var fmt = $"00.{new string('0', precision + 1)}";

foreach (var param1 in new[]{"0.0","22.00", "77.777777777777"})
{
    Decimal convertDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(param1);

    String temp = convertDecimal.ToString(fmt);
    Console.WriteLine(temp[..^1]); // temp = temp[..^1]; for later use
}
```

Output:

```
00.0000000
22.0000000
77.7777777    # temp is 77.77777778 - the 8 is sliced off the string
```

If you can not use slicing use `string.substring(..)` with lenght-1 instead.